# batch updating processing with csom (Timeout issue)

Tags: csom, updatelistitems, batch

I have just over 800 records i'm trying to update but I keep getting timeout error despite the fact i'm setting the timeout to indefinite like below:-
clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1

see my snippet code below

```
function updateMultipleListItems() 
    {   
    var itemArray = [];
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Stop it from timing out (infinite) but doesn't work
    clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

     while(ListItemToBeUpdated.moveNext())
     {
        var oItem = ListItemToBeUpdated.get_current();
        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
        console.log(oListItem);
        console.log(oItem.get_id());

        oListItem.set_item('UpdateField', 'Update');  
        oListItem.update();
        console..log("updated yes");
        itemArray.push(oListItem);
        clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
     }  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(updateMultipleListItemsSuccess, updateMultipleListItemsFailed);
}
```

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Try this one
`clientContext.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;`

Comment: Thanks Ankit but is there any differences with clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1 ?

Comment: Hi Ankit, The System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite; didn't make any difference. Still getting the timeout  error

Comment: I had the same issue and setting the time to infinite worked for me. Could you let me know where are you running this code. Like in a console application or in a SharePoint page. Because I have often seen that when the system goes into sleep mode after a long idle time the console application stops working.

Comment: Its javascript using CSOM on a webpage